# Git raising conflicts for simple merges

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I'm having issues with a BitBucket repository whereby, upon performing merges from one branch to another (this can be any branch, it happens regularly) it raises conflicts for very simple changes. For example, the only difference between two versions of a file is that one branch added a new method and the other did not. Sometimes it even raises a conflict where the line has not changed on either branch.

I've been using Git for a few years at different companies and haven't seen this kind of issue before. We have quite a few problems with Git and bad merges where work has been lost or lots of regression issues introduced following merges.

Could this be a setting that is causing Git to be super cautious about what constitutes a conflict?

Comment: Line endings perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, good call. I know we have had some issues with line endings. I'll look in to that.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you can't manage branches properly,

*Ex:* you have 3 branches:

1. master
2. developer1
3. developer2

If one `developer1` changes some code it would be firstly merge with `master` and then you should `rebase` that in `developer2` branch

If both `developer1` and `developer2` have code changes so it would be `merge` in `master` then you have to `rebase` respected branch

If you follow versioning then your branch structure like:

`master` => `1.0.0, 2.0.0` => `developer1, developer2`

In this merging will be `developer1` => `versiobranch(1.0.0)` => `master`

So it will may be help when your project follow versioning